# Sublime Text 2/3 - How to always have at least 10 lines under current line?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to show at least x number of lines below a current line in ST? Say my cursor is on line 55, I want Sublime to display at least 10 more lines below the current line so line 55 will never be at the bottom of the screen. Is this possible in Sublime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build 4075 added a setting called `scroll_context_lines` for this.

If you are using an older build, you can achieve this with a simple plugin, that listens for cursor movement events.

From the `Tools` menu in Sublime Text, click `New Plugin`.
Replace the contents with the following:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ShowLinesUnderSelectionListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def show_lines_under_selection(self, view, number_of_lines_to_show):
        cursor_pos = view.sel()[0].end()
        row, col = view.rowcol(cursor_pos)
        desired_pos = view.text_point(row + number_of_lines_to_show, col)
        if not view.visible_region().contains(desired_pos):
            view.show(desired_pos, False)
    
    def on_post_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if command_name in ('word_highlight_click', 'move', 'move_to', 'insert'):
            self.show_lines_under_selection(view, 10)
    
    def on_post_window_command(self, window, command_name, args): # for Vintageous support
        if command_name in ('press_key'):
            self.show_lines_under_selection(window.active_view(), 10)
```

Save it to the folder it suggests as something like `show_lines_under_cursor.py`.

This will ensure that there are always 10 visible lines under the cursor. Note that once you reach the bottom of the file, it won't scroll any further to show 10 non-existing-in-file lines. I'm not sure if this is possible via the API.

Comment: So close! I use Vintageous (a Vim plugin for Sublime), and the above code only works when I'm in insert mode. Do you have a way to hack it so it works with Vim's navigation mode as well?

Comment: @NigelNg I have updated the code, which I hope will allow it to work with Vim's navigation mode... Completely untested, but I based it on the fact that the keymap that Vintageous uses rebinds everything to a Window Command called `press_key`, so I'm hoping it will work... :)

Comment: Thanks Keith, but it still doesn't work. The console shows this error every time I hit a Vim navigation key
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 411, in on_post_window_command
    callback.on_post_window_command(window, name, args)
  File "C:\Users\nigel.ng\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\show_lines_under_cursor.py", line 17, in on_post_window_command
    self.show_lines_under_selection(view, 10)
NameError: global name 'view' is not defined`

Comment: whoops, I made a mistake - it should be fixed now, could you try the code in my latest edit please :)

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! May I know what you changed to make it work?

Comment: @Nigel, of course you may :) take a took at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34921263/revisions) - I had referenced a variable `view` which didn't exist, so I changed it to get the active view for the window.

Comment: @KeithHall Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed as well.  I want to have surrounding context for my lines, so I added a `show_lines_above_selection` method, changed the calculation for `desired_pos` to use `-` instead of `+` and added a call to it from both of the other methods.